# How to merge two drives on a USB key into one?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I am trying to create a bootable USB key for Ubuntu, but there are two drives showing up (`D:` and `E:`). `D:` is preventing `E:` (the drive with the ISO) from booting.

**Is there any way to merge these drives?**

[image: image shows the 2 drives]

---

Disk Management screenshot:

[image: image shows disk management screen]

Comment: Are `D:` and `E:` shown as separate devices in Disk Management? or two partitions inside a single device?

Comment: Yes, they are 2 separate drives in disk management

Comment: they are 2 separate drives @kamil

Comment: I'm afraid you can't merge them. My phone presents itself also as two drives: a part of its internal memory first, then SD card. With proper firmware magic the phone could "merge" these devices (e.g. like JBOD) but I haven't heard of such a firmware. Your situation may be similar – the USB key has two distinct memory areas. If so, maybe the better question would be "how to boot form the second one?". Is `D:` writable? What is its size?

Comment: Its read only (I didnt see that at first). @kamil

Comment: Tough luck. My bet is you definitely can't merge them. Moreover `D:` reports as *read only* so you cannot place a bootloader there that would chainload `E:`. I suspect there is no way to boot from `E:` without a bootlader elsewhere (and carrying a bootloader on one USB and ISO on the other makes no sense). I wish I'm wrong.

Comment: could you delete :D ? Or would that delete drive :E as well because it is all in one usb key @kamil

Comment: I suspect your USB key is (on logical level) a USB hub with two devices connected. Even if you could delete the `D:` partition/filesystem (and I think you can't), the device would still be there and this setup would still prevent `E:` from booting.

Comment: @kamil darn it..... guess i need to find a new usb key. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: I'm a random guy on the Internet. I may be wrong.

Comment: What's the brand/model of this USB key?

Comment: @Ploni it doesnt say